# Printing pattern using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Can anybody help me why my kernel died when I run this code

below is the question:

> given a positive integer `n` and another positive integer 
>       `k < n`. 
>   
> Input: `n = 16 k=5`
>   
>   such that  Output: `16, 11, 6, 1, -4, 1, 6, 11, 16`

code:

```
def myfunc(no,nr,k,lis=[]):    
    lis.append(nr)
    if nr>=0:
        return myfunc(no,nr-k,k,lis)
    else:
        if no==nr:
            return lis
        else:    
            return myfunc(no,nr+k,k,lis)

myfunc(16,16,5)
```

Comment: it recurses infinitely since it doesn't reach the base case to exit out of the recursion.

Comment: Your problem description isn't clear. You gave sample input and output, but no explanation of how they're related.

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel is crashing because the function will never reach the base case. For the particular call you gave, the call trace will look like this:

```
myfunc(16, 16, 5)
  myfunc(16, 11, 5)
    myfunc(16, 6, 5)
      myfunc(16, 1, 5)
        myfunc(16, -4, 5)
          myfunc(16, 1, 5)
```

with the last two calls repeating forever. You don't have a proper base case. I am not sure what your intended behavior is for the function, but you need a base case that will definitely be reached by all possible inputs, such as:

```
if nr < 0:
    return lis
```

Answer (score 0):

It is infinite recursion as it go like 16 to 11 to 6 to 1 to -4. After that infinite recursion starts i.e -4 to 1 and 1 to -4 like that.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out

def myfunc(nr,k,lis=[],flag=True):

```
lis.append(nr)
if flag:
    if nr>0:
        return myfunc(nr-k,k,lis)
    else:
        flag=False
if not flag:
    if nr==lis[0]:
        return lis
    else:    
        return myfunc(nr+k,k,lis,False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting infinite recursion because you are not testing your exit condition correctly.  Also, it would seem to me that the function should  append to the list if gets from itself instead of updating it through parameter passing.

But do you really need to use recursion for this ?   It seems that the result could be obtained directly using two ranges:

```
def myFunc(n,k):
      return [*range(n,-k,-k),*range(n%k,n+1,k)]
```

output:

```
myFunc(16,5) # [16, 11, 6, 1, -4, 1, 6, 11, 16]
```

If you need it to be recursive, you have to find a recursive pattern in the result.  For example, going from both sides towards the middle decreases by k until a negative value is reached:

```
def myFunc(n,k):
      if n<=0: return [n]
      return [n]+myFunc(n-k,k)+[n]
```